# How to correct this error when I'm trying to get a new access token for Imgur with Postman?

Tags: postman, imgur

To use the Imgur API, I have to use their Postman collection.
Here's the instructions that doesn't work for me :

> In Postman, under the main request builder panel, click the Authorization tab. Click the Get New Access Token button. Set Auth URL to https://api.imgur.com/oauth2/authorize and Access Token URL to https://api.imgur.com/oauth2/token. Add the Client ID and Client Secret you received from registering your application above, then click Request Token

So I'm doing the following step :

Imgur API collection --> Authorization --> Type : OAuth 2.0 --> press button "Get New Access Token"

and here's the error when I click : [Postman Authentification Failed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lyJQV.png)

And I tried to check the console but I don't get where the error is from.

The error in the console is :

> GET http://localhost:10533/knockknock net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED

Thanks for your help !

Comment: What was the error in the console ?

Comment: @Akio The error in the console was : "GET http://localhost:10533/knockknock net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED"